# Count frequency of same value in several columns

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I'm facing a problem which I guess is quite easy to fix but I couldn't find the answer.

I have a dataframe called **clg** where basically I have 3 columns `date, X1, X2`. 
`X1` and `X2` are name of country teams. `X1` and `X2` have the same list of countries.

I'm simply trying to count the frequency of each country in the two columns as a total.

So far, I've only been able to count the frequency of the `X1` column but I didn't find a way to sum both columns.

```
clt <- as_tibble(na.omit(count(clg, clg$X1)))
```

I would like to get a data frame where in the first columns I have unique countries, and in the second column the sum of occurrences in `X1 + X2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use`unlist()` and `table()` to get the overall counts.  Wrapping it in `data.frame()` will give you the desired two column output.

```
clg <- data.frame(date=1:3, 
                  X1=c("nor", "swe", "alg"), 
                  X2=c("swe", "alg", "jpn"))

data.frame(table(unlist(clg[c("X1", "X2")])))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1  alg    2
# 2  nor    1
# 3  swe    2
# 4  jpn    1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can `gather` into 'long' format and then do the `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(clg, key, Var1, -date) %>%
     count(Var1)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Var1      n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 alg       2
#2 jpn       1
#3 nor       1
#4 swe       2
```

#### data

```
clg <- structure(list(date = 1:3, X1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("alg", 
"nor", "swe"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("alg", "jpn", "swe"), class = "factor")),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your goal with two steps. In the first step, you calculate the sum of occurrences for each country. In the next step, you're joining the two df's together and calculate the total sum.

```
   X1_sum <- df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(X1) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(n_x1 = n())

   X2_sum <- df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(X2) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(n_x2 = n()

   final_summary <- X1_sum %>%
      # merging data with by country names
      dplyr::left_join(., X2_sum, by = c("X1", "X2")) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(n_sum = n_x1 + n_x2)
```